# How are the widths of nested absolutely positioned elements determined?

Tags: css

Example:

```
<style>
     div {
         position:absolute; left:auto; right:auto; width:auto;
         margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
     }
</style>
<div id="containingBlock">
    foo
    <div id="inner">this is my text</div>
</div>
```

To determine the widths of both divs, we need the *shrink-to-fit* algorithm in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width *

Let's start with `#inner`:

- get the *preferred minimum width*

  ```
   this
   is
   my
   text
  |----| preferred minimum width
  ```
- get the *preferred width*

  ```
   this is my text
  |---------------| preferred width
  ```
- compare both to *available width*:

  ```
  computed width = min(max(preferred minimum width, available width),
                       preferred width)
  ```

  Easy. But what is *available width*? Since we got no margins/paddings/borders, it's simply the width of `containingBlock`. But now we get an infinite loop, since the same algorithm applies again:
- get the *preferred minimum width* of containingBlock

  ```
   foo
   +-------+
   | inner |
   +-------+
  |--?????--| preferred minimum width
  ```

In other words: to get the width of `inner`, we must know the width of `containingBlock` and vice versa.

In reality, it looks like browsers just assume `available width = 0` in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/pxvJJ/6/.
But this is not covered by the specs, or am I missing something obvious?

* <sub>(note that this spec has not yet been superseded by CSS3)</sub>

Comment: Position absolute will remove both from the normal document flow. So the preferred minimum width of `#containingBlock` does not care for the processed width of `#inner`. The available width for `#inner` is based on its first ancestor, which results in the length of the text `foo`.

Comment: @RenéGeuze I can't see that. The calculation of *available width* is precisely defined [in 10.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width): solve the equation `'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block`, for `width` after setting `left=right=0`

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - that's not what RenéGeuze is saying (I think). He's saying that the inner block (or its contents) does not participate in the calculation of the preferred minimum width (or preferred width) of the containing block, leaving the containing block to shrink-wrap around what's left (i.e. the "foo" text), and thereby breaking the dependency loop.

Comment: @Alohci - spot on. I indeed tried explaining it's not an infinite loop and therefor the width is not just some quasi random assumption. My apologies for not being able to find the necessary words to write a comprehensive acceptable answer. It's a great question in my eyes, I like the in depth research into the specs and browser behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I guess that's what browsers actually do, so @RenéGeuze is right. Indeed, "CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm.", and as a consequence to the above, skipping absolutely positioned child nodes with no explicit width is required for such algorithm to work.

Answer (score 2):

If we read carefully through the specs, we'll [find that](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width)

> CSS 2.1 does not define the exact [shrink-to-fit] algorithm.

It's supposed to be

> similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm

which, in turn, [is implementation-dependent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout).

So, the above example shows that excluding `#inner` from the calculation of containingBlock's *preferred minimum width* may be a good idea when implementing a straight-forward algorithm, and we'd end up with this:

```
|---| preferred minimum width
 foo
 +-------+
 | inner |
 +-------+
|--?????--|
```

which is probably what browsers do.

---

That being said, the question is: Which elements **do** actually contribute to containingBlock's *preferred minimum width*?

Let's see what happens if `#inner` has `position:static; width: auto`. This case is even harder. Again, [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) give the constraint

> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block

with no shrink-to-fit allowed this time. And, again, it cannot be solved. Or can it? Funny enough, it can! Let's see what actually happens: http://jsfiddle.net/pxvJJ/12/

[image: screenshot of jsfiddle.net/pxvJJ/12/]

Apparently, the statically positioned divs are treated differently. So I suppose the algorithm to determine width of containing block goes like this:

1. determine the *preferred width* of all contained block boxes **in normal flow**.
2. set width of containing block = maximum of those preferred widths
3. calculate the width of **all** contained boxes, now that width of containing block is known

I am still confused as to why (all) browsers do this. There seems to be no reason for treating absolutely positioned elements differently in this regard.